# Is it possible to dual boot without sharing drives?

Tags: windows, security, multi-boot

Is there any way to have dual boot set up on 2 different drives, say 2 different versions of windows that do NOT have access to the other drive? So that if one gets infected with malware, the other would still be fine.

I know physically unplugging the drive is one way but doing it too often would probably wear out the connectors.

Comment: You might be able to add a multi throw power switch to the HDD power lines. Alternatively would USB 3 external drives work for you?

Comment: It might be worth checking the cost of a suitable second-hand computer for one of the drives.

Comment: @davidgo From what I read, Windows can't be installed on external drives. That's an Enterprise only feature or something like that.

Comment: ESATA maybe ? Not sure if they are.more robust connectors though.

Comment: FWIW one of the labs I used to teach in had removable drives in cages.  Worked great, since the lab was shared between Windows desktop/server, Novell Netware, and Linux classes, plus standard "how to use word" type stuff.

Comment: @ivanivan I've considered the option but I'm not sure how durable the SATA connector is and if it would handle being plugged and unplugged several times per week.

Comment: the product we used was designed for it, drive bay replacement w/ rails and a serious connector that had the standard power and SATA/IDE on the back side.  And the drives were in "cartridges", again with the special connectors on outside.  Think the issue that you'll have is actually finding a system like that today ... I know that cheap/free/easy virtualization got us to move away from them.

Comment: Oracle's Virtual Box is free.  I allows you to run Windows in a virtual box.

Comment: If both OS' are windows 8.1/10/11 pro, you may use Bitlocker. I write a tutorial about that over here which depicts every step and names every command: https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33649/Bitlocker-and-multi-booting.html

Answer (score 1):

A disk or partition are not accessible without a drive-letter, and the drive-letter
assignments are stored in the registry, so are separately defined for each of the
Windows versions.

The solution is then to boot both Windows installation, one after the other,
and for each one remove the drive-letter of the other.

To remove a drive-letter:

- Run Disk Management
- Right-click the disk and select *Change Drive Letter and Paths*
- Click *Remove*
- Click *Yes*

For more information with screenshots see the article
[How to Remove a Drive Letter in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/107032-remove-drive-letter-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: this is not correct.  Windows can access drives without letters.

Comment: @Keltari: Only special apps can access partitions without drive-letter.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution: unmount the other drive from within each system upon the first boot.

Comment: How would that be done permanently? Also, wouldn't root access be able to mount them any time?

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas...

Wire in a couple of DPST switches on the sata power lines (mount them in a spare front bay). Or use a DPDT switch... that way its only ever one drive powered at a time.

Or more simply, you could use some combination of molex/sata power extension/adaptor cables to power these drives, then simply unplug from the middle... if you do wareout a cable, it's a cheap replacement!

Finally, you might be able to find a hot swappable sata hdd caddy (*these were big for a while way back when in the pata days*) to do the job (maybe even with front panel power switches), but this will obviously be a more expensive option.

Super silly bonus round... install one Windoze OS as a VM on an ext4 based GNU/Linux OS... the other Win Hdd wont have a clue on whats going on over there! :-)

Comment: It's really unfortunate that there are no easy ways to do it, so I'll think about getting the switch or extensions. Also, I love your super silly bonus round. I've tried thinking of a lot of ways to do it but totally missed that combo. :)

Answer (score 0):

Full disk encryption, Encrypt both volumes with different passwords.

If it is that important you can buy 2 different hard drives and have both installed and fully encrypted with different passwords.

Don't enter the password for OS #2, when inside OS #1 and visa versa.

If a disk access password prompt occurs click cancel, instead.

The only remaining risk, is the virus might be able to wipe or double encrypt the volume.  The password prompt should block this, but some clever hacker might figure something out.

A physical write blocker works, but then you can't save anything to the drive either.

[https://www.amazon.com/Coolgear-SATA-Adapter-Write-Protect-Selection/dp/B005C55OYA](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005C55OYA)

I think this one has a switch.

Comment: BitLocker only encrypts the partition where the os is installed and not the EFI partition. Couldn't that be an issue?

Comment: As far as I know, neither VeraCrypt nor BitLocker support a dual-boot setup where both OSes are encrypted.

Comment: @Alex the EFI partition has only bootable data, and not user data and its approx 32mb in size.  Each OS seeing the EFI partition is not significant.

Comment: I doubt that encryption helps when it comes to "access" by e.g. ransomware.

Comment: @TomYan  How will the ransomware access the other drive when its encrypted with a different password?

Comment: BitLocker-ish encryption itself cannot / does not stop anything from performing block-level write (or even, SCSI commands directly sent from a userspace program), AFAIK. Essentially the job of encryption is really just to prevent the data on a drive from being "interpreted" without authorization, by converting "plaintext" to "ciphertext" for data written via the encryption engine (or container, whatever you call it). Though I have never checked if Windows has extra mechanism (hopefully cannot be circumvented, if any) to prevent the aforementioned low-level access *when a drive is encrypted*.

Comment: But mechanism like ATA password (or *maybe* Opal, which I have no experience with) does somewhat block access to the drive (instead of just the data), when the drive *is not unlocked* (or again, when the mechanism is not circumvented).

Answer (score 0):

Somehow nobody mentioned that the OP can consider disabling the drive in *Device Manager*.

I suppose e.g. ransomeware "thoughtful" enough will probably be capable of finding out all disabled drive as well and enable them back (or access them via some even lower level method that I don't know of). Still, since it makes the drive "go away" right down to the drive emumeration level, I think the bottom line is that it makes more sense than the suggestion of removing drive letter or setting up encryption / BitLocker. At the very least you'll be safe from yourself when you run some "raw drive writer" that write to a choice from the enumaration of `\\.\PhysicalDriveN`s (i.e. `Disk N`s you can see in Disk Management).